# x2=15.5*sin(84) , print(x2), gives 10.2 , but print(15.5*sin(84)) gives correct val=-15.49xx

Tags: python-3.7

Within my python code , the print( X2 ), were `X2=15.5*sin(84)` gives, 10.2xx , while  `print(15.5*sin(84) )`, gives -15.4xx  ? Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: When I did this I got the same answer. But it was different than both of yours.

Comment: Like @WJS said, I also got same for both but my answer was `11.36444996113603`

Comment: Could add a screenshot of your output? We all get the correct answer ```11.36444996113603```

Comment: BTW, the sin(84)  (where 84 is in radians) is in the second quadrant so it must be positive, and so must your answer.